# Combine 2 Select Queries from DB2 into one Result

Tags: sql, db2, pivot, union

i have two queries on my DB2 database:

```
SELECT XEDCDTA.DCADR.ADRNAME as Name, 
XEDCDTA.DCADR.ADRCITY as City, 
XEDCDTA.DCDDT.DDTGRMA as Gross,
XEDCDTA.DCDDT.DDTCOCD as TN,
XEDCDTA.DCDDT.DDTDES as Description,
XEDCDTA.DCDDT.DDTVATVA as VATVALUE,
XEDCDTA.DCDHD.DHDTRN as TRUCK,
XEDCDTA.DCDHD.DHDTRE as REFEENCE,
FROM XEDCDTA.DCDHD, XEDCDTA.DCDDT, XEDCDTA.DCADR
WHERE XEDCDTA.DCDHD.DHDTRE LIKE ('123456') AND 
XEDCDTA.DCADR.ADRTYPE LIKE ('ABC') AND
XEDCDTA.DCDDT.DHDKEY = XEDCDTA.DCDHD.DHDKEY AND
XEDCDTA.DCADR.DHDKEY = XEDCDTA.DCDHD.DHDKEY
```

and the second Query

```
SELECT
XEDCDTA.DCADR.ADRREF as Reference2
FROM XEDCDTA.DCDHD, XEDCDTA.DCDDT, XEDCDTA.DCADR
WHERE XEDCDTA.DCDHD.DHDTRE LIKE ('123456') AND 
XEDCDTA.DCADR.ADRTYPE LIKE ('XYZ') AND
XEDCDTA.DCDDT.DHDKEY = XEDCDTA.DCDHD.DHDKEY AND
XEDCDTA.DCADR.DHDKEY = XEDCDTA.DCDHD.DHDKEY
```

I tried:

```
SELECT XEDCDTA.DCADR.ADRNAME as Name, 
XEDCDTA.DCADR.ADRCITY as City, 
XEDCDTA.DCDDT.DDTGRMA as Gross,
XEDCDTA.DCDDT.DDTCOCD as TN,
XEDCDTA.DCDDT.DDTDES as Description,
XEDCDTA.DCDDT.DDTVATVA as VATValue,
XEDCDTA.DCDHD.DHDTRN as Truck,
XEDCDTA.DCDHD.DHDTRE as Reference1,
cast(NULL as varchar(128)) as Reference2
FROM XEDCDTA.DCDHD, XEDCDTA.DCDDT, XEDCDTA.DCADR
WHERE XEDCDTA.DCDHD.DHDTRE LIKE ('123456') AND 
XEDCDTA.DCADR.ADRTYPE LIKE ('ABC') AND
XEDCDTA.DCDDT.DHDKEY = XEDCDTA.DCDHD.DHDKEY AND
XEDCDTA.DCADR.DHDKEY = XEDCDTA.DCDHD.DHDKEY 
UNION ALL
SELECT cast(NULL as varchar(128)) as Name, 
cast(NULL as varchar(128)) as City, 
cast(NULL as varchar(128)) as Gross,
cast(NULL as varchar(128)) as TN,
cast(NULL as varchar(128)) as Description,
cast(NULL as varchar(128)) as VATValue,
cast(NULL as varchar(128)) as Truck,
cast(NULL as varchar(128)) as Reference1,
XEDCDTA.DCADR.ADRREF as Reference2
FROM XEDCDTA.DCDHD, XEDCDTA.DCDDT, XEDCDTA.DCADR
WHERE XEDCDTA.DCDHD.DHDTRE LIKE ('123456') AND 
XEDCDTA.DCADR.ADRTYPE LIKE ('XYZ') AND
XEDCDTA.DCDDT.DHDKEY = XEDCDTA.DCDHD.DHDKEY AND
XEDCDTA.DCADR.DHDKEY = XEDCDTA.DCDHD.DHDKEY ) s
```

But from this query the result rows are filled with "NULL". Only the column Reference2 has been filled with the values from the query.

The result should look like something like that:

Name, City, Gross, TN, Description, VATValue, Truck, Reference, Reference2

DHDKEY is the primary key for all the tables.

Can anyone give me a hint?

I also tried some statements which worked for mysql, but i got an exception in DB2.

Thanks for any help.

Cheers Claudio

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
XEDCDTA.DCDHD.DHDKEY AS DHDKEY,
XEDCDTA.DCADR.ADRTYPE AS ADRTYPE,
XEDCDTA.DCADR.ADRNAME AS Name, 
XEDCDTA.DCADR.ADRCITY AS City, 
XEDCDTA.DCDDT.DDTGRMA AS Gross,
XEDCDTA.DCDDT.DDTCOCD AS TN,
XEDCDTA.DCDDT.DDTDES AS Description,
XEDCDTA.DCDDT.DDTVATVA AS VATValue,
XEDCDTA.DCDHD.DHDTRN AS Truck,
CASE WHEN XEDCDTA.DCADR.ADRTYPE = 'ABC' THEN XEDCDTA.DCDHD.DHDTRE ELSE NULL END AS Reference1,
CASE WHEN XEDCDTA.DCADR.ADRTYPE = 'XYZ' THEN XEDCDTA.DCADR.ADRREF ELSE NULL END AS Reference2
FROM XEDCDTA.DCDHD
INNER JOIN XEDCDTA.DCDDT ON XEDCDTA.DCDDT.DHDKEY = XEDCDTA.DCDHD.DHDKEY
INNER JOIN XEDCDTA.DCADR ON XEDCDTA.DCADR.DHDKEY = XEDCDTA.DCDHD.DHDKEY 
WHERE XEDCDTA.DCDHD.DHDTRE = ('123456')
AND XEDCDTA.DCADR.ADRTYPE IN ('ABC','XYZ')
```